# Jwt authenticaton in c# wpf application

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

I started learning c# two days ago so I don't have much experience with the .net framework. I want to create an application where the user can input a username/password combination and the login information will be sent to the server for verification. I thought of doing it in the following way by using a PHP script but its not really efficient/secure since everyone will have access to the script.

**1) client->Get username/password from user and send the username to the server

2) server->Find out if the user is in the database and send a random number back

3) client->Create an MD5 hash out of the number then create an MD5 out of the passwordMD5+numberMD5\ and send it back to the server with the number

4) server->Create and MD5 hash from the numberHash+passwordHash and compare it the hash received by the client**

The other problem with the authentication above is that I want to periodically check if the user is authorized to access the application after it has sign in and I don't want to keep asking for numbers from the website every time the user wants to access something in the application. I did some research and found out about JWT authentication, but the issue I'm having now is implementing JWT authentication in an efficient way. If the user signs into the application it will send the username/password to the server but it doesn't seem safe to send plain passwords the the server. I also want the tokens to have a time limit after it is created. I was thinking about creating a new database for expired tokens and another one for valid tokens and check those database every time the user tries to access information from the site. I was about implementing some kind of API with asp.net core but I found out the host I'm currently using does not support .net. Now I'm thinking about using a server(maybe azure but I'm not familiar with it) just for generating the keys and when the client tries to contact my website I check if the key exist in the invalid key database and block the connection otherwise if its not in the valid key database insert it.

**My questions:**

**1) I there a better way of achieving this other than the way above.

2) If not then what would be the best way of checking the keys to give client access the website database.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you possibly looked into using Auth0 for protecting your server and your WPF application? Check out https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/wpf-winforms for more information as you can probably implement this using the free tier they offer.

Comment: It looks like that's a exactly what I want, but I'm looking to implemented my self

Comment: @Nice Rolling your own authentication system is exactly how people get into trouble. Authentication is a complex beast, and it's extremely easy to inadvertently add some vulnerability to your system. Best to stick with established tools and patterns from reputable sources (such as Auth0 or [Duende](https://duendesoftware.com/) (creators of Identity Server))